# for loop with incremenation of 5

Tags: c++

Use a counter named count that has an initial value of 1, a final value of 20, and an increment of 5.

```
for(int count=1; count<20; count=count+5)
cout<<count<<endl;
```

Is the correct approch?

Comment: Yes. but final value will be 21.

Comment: Is this the correct appraoch?? Depends on what you want to do, if you want to get 1,6,11,16 printed on the screen, this is a way to do it.

Comment: but the output is printing as 1,6,11,16.... 16 is final value..

Comment: @dd2 the final value will be `16`.

Comment: If the first sentence is a task given to you, then you can tell the teacher that it is immpossible to repeatedly add 5 to 1 and end up with a value of 20....

Comment: To clarify - while the final value passed to cout is 16, the value of count when the loop ends is 21.

Comment: @UKmonkey But because the variable is a for-loop local it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's impossible to say whether the code is correct without knowing what it's supposed to do. The code will run through a set of values. If those are the values that you want, it's correct; if they aren't, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya correct ..
start with initial point 1 and final value of 20 , increment by 5

**for(int count=1; count<=20; count=count+5)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or the shorthand version :

```
for(int count=1; count<=20; count+=5)
```

Your values will be 1 , 6 , 11 , 16 though. It won't get to 20 so the question is a bit off.

Side note, I see you using `cout`, this means you either have `using namespace std;` or `using std::cout;`, the latter is fine, the former [not so much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Boost.Range](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.range-helper-classes-and-functions). The [interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) is quite straighforward and you are explicitly showing your intention which is importan with custom loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>

int main() {
    for (auto i: boost::irange(1, 20, 5)) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Stream output operator is already overload so you'll get the value from the type you want.

You can [try it](https://ideone.com/NFE6yT) live.

Answer (score 0):

ya correct .. start with initial point 1 and final value of 20 , increment by 5

```
for(int count=1; count<=20; count=count+5)
```

Answer (score 0):

start with initial point 1 and final value of 20 , increment by 5

> for(int count=1; count<=20; count=count+5)